# Filling a screw hole that turned crooked and broke the surface of a hollow core door

Tags: wood, doors, woodworking, pocket-door

I installed the hardware for this pocket door about 1/8" too close to the front edge of the door. The screw holes are not only in the wrong place now, but they turned diagonal and broke out the inner surface of the cutout.

When I reinstall the hardware, the new holes will only be 1/8" behind the current ones (*and will hopefully be straight and not track into the old diagonal holes*).

I've seen the common advice about using dowels and/or sawdust and wood glue to fill holes like this, but it seems in this case like it might be harder due to the broken surface (*it's now no longer a simple hole*).

Are there are any more specific tips I should be aware of for this unique case?

[image: Door cutout]

Comment: 1/8th of an inch from the edge of the opening does not give you much structure to screw too without blowing out the edge. Is there room in the hardware to accommodate gluing a small piece of wood on there?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thought. Keep in mind this (misplaced) screw was far less than that even. But I measured and I think I can fit a 1/16" skin panel in there to beef up the reinforcement for my bad threads. I won't bond it in place until I'm sure it fits behind the latch. Then will probably just use some sort of wood putty to fill the hole, since the dowel trick won't work due to the diagonal nature of this hole (it ends up being conical rather than cylindrical). Any recs for the filler to use? Thanks!

Comment: How did “they turn diagonal”? And how will you prevent that happening again? Mount the drill in a drill stand to keep it under control?

Comment: With no edge strength I would suggest thru bolting with a #6 machine screw.  Guessing on the size. This will mean having to drill a hole through the door. 
The screws pulling the 2 plates of metal together and the center section that is fresh undisturbed MDF or whatever will provide plenty of strength to suspend the door.

Comment: @SolarMike they turned diagonal because they were installed way too close to the edge. The latch hardware needs one more notch cut on the front surface of the door before it can sit flush, and at that point the holes will be further back from the edge. But yes because of the existing crooked threads, I may drill a very narrow pilot hole to encourage the screw to go straight next time. Considering even just drilling a 1/8" thru hole and then gluing a 1/8" dowel in it.